# Function that computes trimmed means for a dataframe, error message: Error in nrow(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I'd like to make a function that computes trimmed means for all columns of a data frame, with multiple trimming portions.

Here's the code:

```
tmean1 <- function(data, alpha){
  tmean_est <- depthTools::tmean(data = data, alpha = alpha)
  tmean_est}
tmean1 <- Vectorize(FUN = tmean1, vectorize.args = "alpha")
```

The error message I get is:  `Error in nrow(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default`. I thought that the `tmean` function doesn't recognise the `alpha` argument, but I have defined `alpha` outside of the function as well, and it still doesn't recognise it. Maybe someone is able to recognise the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
tmean1 <- function(data, alpha){
  tmean(data, alpha)$tm
}

tmean1 <- Vectorize(FUN = tmean1, vectorize.args = "alpha")
```

example output:

```
## > tmean1(data = df, alpha = c(.1, .2))
##                   [,1] [,2]
## Sepal.Length 4.9500000 4.86
## Sepal.Width  3.3833333 3.28
## Petal.Length 1.4500000 1.40
## Petal.Width  0.2333333 0.20
```

(did you remember to assign/reassing `tmean1 <- Vectorize( etc.` ?)

Alternatively, you could use the convenience of {tidyr}. *df* being your data frame to derive trimmed means for ...

```
## example data:
df <- 
  iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)
```

... you can create a result dataframe, starting out with column *alpha* (specifying the desired alphas) like this:

```
library(depthTools)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data.frame(alpha = c(0.1, 0.2)) %>% ## choose alpha levels
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(tmean = list(tmean(df, alpha)$tm)) %>%
  unnest_wider(tmean)
```

output of above example:

```
## # A tibble: 2 x 5
##   alpha Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
##   <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
## 1   0.1         4.95        3.38         1.45       0.233
## 2   0.2         4.86        3.28         1.4        0.2
```